# How can I call and execute a function stored in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have function `getArray(pram1, pram2)` stored in database (MySQL) and it returns data in an array. 
When I pass the query, it returns the function name as I stored it in the database, 
but does not execute this function.

The code, which I'm using, is this:

```
$result=eval("return \$ret = $db_query_function;");
$db_query_function is variable that have function name getArray(pram1, pram2).
```

Error generated **eval()'d code**

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use call_user_func().

```
call_user_func('function_name', $parameter);
```

Comment: function definition store in database

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's probably not the best solution to store functions in the database.

If you want to store function *implementations* in the database, you'll have to store only the function body and parameter list separately, (but no name should be given to the function) so you can use [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) to put your function into a variable at runtime.

for example:

```
function add($a, $b)
{
    return $a + $b;
}
```

should end up in variables similar to:

```
$arguments = '$a, $b'; // note single quotes, no variable expansion!
$implementation = 'return $a + $b;'; // single quotes again

$myFunction = create_function($arguments, $implementation);
```

now you can call your function:

```
$sum = $myFunction(10, 20); // $sum will now hold 30
```

If you just want your code stored in the database to be run, all you need is [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

In both cases, you're most likely (but not definitely) missing a better/easier way to deal with yout code. In your sample, the most likely error is that pram1 and pram2 require a dollar sign in the string, but the code sample is incomplete enough to be sure. could also be that the function doesn't exist or you're missing a semicolon, or...

try:

```
$result = eval('return '.$db_query_function);

getArray(pram1, pram2).
```

Good luck.

Comment: function definition stroe in database